# Borel's Hierarchy of $\bigcup _{n\in \mathbb{N}}[\frac{1}{n+2},\frac{1}{n+1})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, borel-sets

Borel Hierarchy with the usual topology in $\mathbb{R}$

In a similar proof with $[0,1)$, I rewrite this set as $\{0\}\cup (0,1)$ and then said that this is the union of a closed set with an open set, thus it was $\Delta _2^0$. Now with a set like $\displaystyle \bigcup \limits _{n\in \mathbb{N}}\left [\frac{1}{n+2},\frac{1}{n+1}\right )$, I am tempted to say is $\Delta _2^0$, but am not sure how to prove it.

Maybe my reasoning with $[0,1)$ is wrong?

Comment: Isn't $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[{1\over n+2},{1\over n+1})$$ just $(0,1)$ (or $(0, {1\over 2})$ if you don't consider $0$ a natural number)?

Comment: But the union of these sets is not $[\frac{1}{2},1)$?

Comment: No, the union of those sets is $(0,1)$ (or $(0,{1\over 2})$ depending on whether you take $0$ to be a natural number). It may help to write it this way: $$...\cup [{1\over 5}, {1\over 4})\cup [{1\over 4}, {1\over 3})\cup[{1\over 3}, {1\over 2})\cup[{1\over 2}, {1\over 1}).$$ (I'm using the convention that $0\in\mathbb{N}$ here.)